# Batch script - Check if user exists in myfile.txt

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to this so...
I have this so far:
- receive username from external application
- specific users are in mylist.txt file in format:
username1
username2
username3
- CRLF is at end of each line

I'm trying to achieve following:
- compare received username from external app with usernames in mylist.txt
- if username is in mylist.txt send mail "USER %username% from Mylist logged on"
- if username is NOT on mylist.txt send mail "USER %username" logged on"

So far I'm doing it like this:

```
    IF /I "%event%" EQU "100" (
     FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%n in (Mylist.txt) DO (
      IF /I %username% EQU %%n (
       ECHO %date% %time% %username% from Mylist.txt LOGON >> TEST.log
       CALL SEND_MAIL.BAT 1 "%date%-%time% USER:%username% from Mylist.txt LOGON")
    ELSE (
     ECHO %date% %time% %username% LOGON >> TEST.log
     CALL SEND_MAIL.BAT 1 "%date%-%time% USER:%username% from LOGON")
     )
    )
```

Executing script sends me two emails for logon event if user IS in mylist. For users NOT in mylist I receive only one email and that's fine.
I've tried with NEQ but it's the same.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   CALL SEND_MAIL.BAT 1 "%date%-%time% USER:%username% from Mylist.txt LOGON"
 ) ELSE (
```

The syntax requires the `else` to be on the same line as *both* the prior closing `)` and the opening `)`